# AWS API Gateway generated sdk request errors

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've created an API using AWS API Gateway. All of the methods used in the API require IAM authentication.

I tried to test the API locally and got the following exception:

```
myapi.model.MyAPIException: The request signature we   calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret  Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1632)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.doInvoke(ClientHandlerImpl.java:204)
    at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.invoke(ClientHandlerImpl.java:185)
    at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.execute(ClientHandlerImpl.java:93)
    at com.amazonaws.opensdk.protect.client.SdkClientHandler.execute(SdkClientHandler.java:42)
    at myapi.MyAPIClient.myMethod(MyAPIClient.java:101)
    ...
```

For building the request I used the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyAPI client = MyAPI .builder()
                .apiKey(myApiKey)
                .iamCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                .build();

    MyMethodRequest myMethodRequest = new MyMethodRequest().arg(methodArg);

    MyMethodResult result = client.myMethod(myMethodRequest);
}
```

The credentials loaded by the `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` are my credentials which have admin access to all of my AWS services so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It show you an error which say that your credentials AWS aren't valid

Comment: Thanks @Tryliom but I'm sure the right credentials are loaded, and I'm the AWS admin so I have access to all services.

Comment: You use it via AWS Lambda ?

Comment: @Tryliom yes and no. It's intended to be used through Lambda, but the test was done on my local PC. Why do you ask?

Comment: Because i usually code with lambda and the function is not called like this, wait a moment, I search my code

Comment: You will just use lambda in future or other aws services ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended being having entered the wrong `apiKey` for the API.
When I changed it to a valid API key generated by API Gateway everything worked.

Also, you have to make sure the API Key is linked to a valid usage plan or it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Usually class more like:

```
package ...;

public class ListingMusic implements 
RequestHandler<HashMap<String, Object>, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(HashMap<String, Object> input, Context context) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Maybe it can be that your lambda can't start

Comment: thanks, the Lambda code was abbreviated from my example. The problem is not in the Lambda, but in how/what I do to call the api

Comment: do you see any problems in how I invoke the API?

Comment: Give the code of MyAPI.myMethod or a github repo with it for me to understand better

Comment: It's auto generated code by AWS's API Gateway generate code methods. Also due to privacy issues, I can't display it here unfortunately.